# Is Python a good candidate for deployment automation?

Tags: python, scripting-language

I am looking for a scripting language for deployment automation (installing, uninstalling, copying files etc.). Main requirements are: cross-platform, debuggable, good documentation, good IDE (or possible integration with Microsoft Visual Studio).
Is Python a good candidate for this?
I would appreciate any links to success stories of using Python for such purposes. Also I am interested in gathering the statistics related to the Python popularity

Comment: Still quite a subjective question, albeit an improvement over your previous version.. I fear this one will be closed shortly as well.

Comment: Python is good for this because you *don't* need an IDE or Visual Studio integration to work with it.

Comment: FWIW, we use [buildout](http://www.buildout.org/) for our deployment needs, but it's perhaps too specialized for your use cases. Unless you are deploying a python egg-based application, it's probably not what you are looking for.